# bash -c does not set $? as expected

Tags: linux, bash

Why do the following two commands produce different results?

```
$ bash -c "ls BLAH; echo $?; export status=$?; echo $status"
ls: cannot access BLAH: No such file or directory
0
```

^ note the empty line after `0`

```
$ cat test.sh
ls BLAH; echo $?; export status=$?; echo $status
$ bash test.sh
ls: cannot access BLAH: No such file or directory
2
0
```

Comment: What's the point of the `export`? You can just set `status=$?`; there are no subprocesses ever spawned to inherit environment variables, so copying the variable into environment space doesn't add value.

Comment: No real reason other than sanity checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansions of `$?` and `$status` in your first example are done by your current shell - that is before the `bash` you're running ever sees the command string. Use single quotes:

```
$ bash -c 'ls BLAH; echo $?; export status=$?; echo $status'
ls: BLAH: No such file or directory
1
0
```

or otherwise:

```
$ bash -c "ls BLAH; echo \$?; export status=\$?; echo \$status"
ls: BLAH: No such file or directory
1
0
```

Comment: The ol' single vs. double quote issue strikes again. Thanks.